# Стоит ли использовать пропсы для уменьшения количества верстки и как это скажется на поддержке кода?

Tags: reactjs

Стоит ли использовать пропсы для уменьшения количества верстки и как это скажется на поддержке кода?

Как смотрите на передачу данных через пропсы в компонент, где дальше мы просто проходим в цикле для генерации верстки?

```
    <Popup
    data={
      {
        'Данные': ['Данные', 'Данные', 'Данные', 'Данные', 'Данные'],
        'Данные': ['Данные', 'Данные'],
        'Данные': ['Данные', 'Данные', 'Данные', 'Данные'],
      }
    }
    />
```

Comment: Это вполне правильный подход, есои за данные отвечает компоент высшего порядка